# Core Data - Fetching, Sorting and Editing/Updating Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I've dipped my toes into the Core Data pool, and a dark and mysterious pool it is indeed...

I have the following:

An entity named `RAS`.

The following attributes exist in `RAS`:

1. `rasIdentifier` of type `String` (not optional)
2. `rasAutoRetire` of type `Bool` (optional)
3. `rasAutoRetireDate` of type `NSDate` (optional)
4. `rasReassessmentDate` of type `NSDate` (optional)
5. `rasReassesmentDueNow` of type `Bool` (optional)
6. `rasAutoRetireDone` of type `Bool` (optional)
7. `rasReassessmentDone` of type `Bool` (optional)

When I first save a "record" the following happens:

- If the user selected for the **item to auto-retire on a specific future date**, the values are set as follows:
- `rasIdentifier` gets a unique value.
- `rasAutoRetire` is set to `true`
- `rasAutoRetireDate` is set to a specific date (say a week in the future).
- `rasReassessmentDate` is left blank
- `rasReassessmentDueNow` is set to `false`
- `rasAutoRetireDone` is set to `false`
- `rasReassessmentDone` is set to `false`
- If the user selected for the **item to be reassessed on a specific future date**, the values are set as follows:
- `rasIdentifier` gets a unique value.
- `rasAutoRetire` is set to `false`
- `rasAutoRetireDate` is left blank.
- `rasReassessmentDate` is set to a specific date.
- `rasReassessmentDueNow` is set to `false`
- `rasAutoRetireDone` is left blank
- `rasReassessmentDone` is set to `false`

From the above it should be clear that an item has two options in the future:  to either auto-retire or to be reassessed.

To check if an item has reached and passed its reassessment date I have started writing the following function, but the code is clunky and I am getting nowhere with it, and I would REALLY appreciate some genius help here...  Here goes:

```
func HandleItemsThatNeedReassessment() {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RAS")
var error: NSError?

//Step 1:  Check if database exists
let count = managedObjContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
if count == NSNotFound {

    print("Database does not exist")

} else {

    print("Database exists.  Check now if there are any records.")

    //Step 2:  Check if there are any records in the database

    do {

    let results = try managedObjContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    let varRecordsExist = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        if varrecordsExist.count == 0 {

            print("No records in the database")
            //do nothing further!

        } else {

            print("Yes, there are \(varRecordsExist.count) records in the database.")

            //Step 3:  Select all the existing records that are due for reassessment (and leave those that are due for auto-retirement - for now)
//NO IDEA WHAT TO DO HERE!



                //Step 4:  Check which items are due for reassessment, but exclude those that have already been reassessed (rasReassessmentDone = true)
//NO IDEA WHAT TO DO HERE EITHER!



                //Step 5:  Because the reassessment date is in the past, change the valueForKey("rasReassessmentDueNow") to TRUE
                if varIsAssessmentOverdue == true {
//NO IDEA WHAT TO DO HERE - AGAIN!

                    ??SomethingHere??.setValue(true, forKey: "rasReassessmentDueNow")
//Do this for all items that needs reassessment

                }

                //Step 6:  If any changes were made/values were changed in Step 5, SAVE those changes to Core Data
                if managedObjContext.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try managedObjContext.save()

                        //How do you save these changes???

                    } catch let error as NSError  {
                        NSLog("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

    catch

    let error as NSError {

    print("Print error stuff here \(error)")

    }

}
}
```

Yeah, the attempted code sucks.  I don't even know if my steps are logical.  Is it even possible to do this all at once?  A lot of the above does not make sense to me - despite hours of googling and reading - and a kind, comprehensive explanation would be highly appreciated.

By the way, this function is called in the viewDidLoad of the first view controller of the app, and that's why I do all those checks in Step 1 and Step 2, otherwise things just crash to a grinding halt if there are no records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't check if there is anything in database at the beginning, I would jump straight to step 3.
You just need to specify predicates which match your requirements, for example:

```
    //Step 3:  Select all the existing records that are due for reassessment (and leave those that are due for auto-retirement - for now)
    //You could also combine it with Step 4 in the same predicate:
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == true AND %K == false AND %K = false", "rasReassessmentDueNow", "rasAutoRetire", "rasReassessmentDone")
```

Now create fetch request as you did above, add predicate to the request and run it.

```
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate1

do {

    let results = try managedObjContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    let records = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    ...
```

Now you have an array with object and here you can check count property to see have you got any data.

In step 5 just enumerate the array and check if varIsAssessmentOverdue is true.
But to be honest I would add another predictate to to the predicate above which check the varIsAssessmentOverdue is true (..AND %K == true",.."varIsAssessmentOverdue") in that case you have only the object you want and you can only enumerate the array and set value to required one, every object in the array will be the one you looking for

```
for ras in results {
         // I don't understand what you are trying to do here, all of the items here will be true and you want to change it to true again?
         ras.setValue(value, forKey: attribute)
}
```

Save changes as you have in the code.

Consider this code mostly as pseudo code some bits will require small amendments but you should be able to pick it up.

The idea here is to hit the database as rarely as possible. You should create NSPredicate which brings you back the result with only the data you want, after then just make changes to the data and save it.

Comment: Hi @Greg,  the problem is that initially (when the records are saved) all rasReassessmentDueNow will be set to false, because the reassessment is not due at that point.  I want to check the reassessment dates for all records (rasReassessmentDate) and if a record's reassessment date is in the past, I want to set rasReassessmentDueNow to true for that record, and do the same to other records that qualify.

Comment: As soon as I have a rasReassessmentDueNow value that is equal to true, an indicator on the view controller (user's screen) will turn from say red to green to alert the user that there are reassessments that are now overdue.

Comment: Just amend the predicate, to check the date is in the past use "%K < %@", "rasReassessmentDate", NSDate(). It's that easy. Create the predicate to match all of your requirements (date in the past, property == true, other == false, etc), pass it to fetch and execute it.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot and I'll get back.  Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: No porb. I would recommend you to have a read about NSPredicate in relation to CoreData.

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE what a little (OK, a LOT!) of guidance can do!  Great stuff, @Greg - it works perfectly!  Thanks for explaining it so well!

Comment: Oh, and I've accomplished it in just over 30 lines of code.  Gone is that clunky code I initially had!  Thanks again - I've learned a whole bunch of stuff today.  Kudos!